# Timeline Red Line

Tags: rendering, animation, timeline

[image: Timeline]
In my timeline there is a red line, and I am thinking it might have something to do with blender only rendering one frame instead of the whole animation. What does this red line mean? What can I do to remove it?

Comment: Have you tried switching back to the default theme?  See if it's still there after you do that.

Comment: @MikeBelanger It is not the theme, perhaps an error.

Comment: I can see the "red line" in the image above. It seems you have 3 particles on the selected object. If so, try stacker's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image doesn't show a red line. If the line occurs horizontally above the frame numbers it displays the baked cache steps for the active object.

Full documentation;
https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/timeline.html

Which caches will be displayed can be setup in the menu: View / Cache:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a particle system, rigid body world, or another type of baked physics simulation leaves a line at the bottom. Check the world and particle systems panel and see if there's something there that you added by accident.

Comment: I didn't add anything by accident, maybe its because it hasn't been baked?